# Calling factory service from inside decorator in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Using the [TextAngular plugin](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) and trying to [customize a toolbar](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar), I'm trying to inject my own service (`LinkService`) into the module but I get an `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider` error.

```
module.config(function($provide, LinkService){
    $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions){
        // $delegate is the taOptions we are decorating
        // register the tool with textAngular
        taRegisterTool('colourRed', {
            iconclass: "fa fa-square red",
            action: function(){
                this.$editor().wrapSelection('forecolor', 'red');
                LinkService.createLink(/*...*/)
            }
        });


        // add the button to the default toolbar definition
        taOptions.toolbar[1].push('colourRed');
        return taOptions;
    }]);
});
```

How to do I inject my service into this config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not inject services into the `configuration` block.

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.
>
> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used
>   to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.

We can however craft similar logic into a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). I am unsure of the usage of `LinkService`, but stubbed out as a provider I can see something like the following...

```
module.provider('LinkProvider', function () {
    var link;
    return {
        createLink: function (value) {
            link = value;
        },
        $get: function () {
            return {
                link: 'http://' + link
            }
        }
    }
});

module.config(function (LinkProvider) {
    LinkProvider.createLink('stackoverflow.com');
});
```

See blog [Differences Between Providers In AngularJS](http://blog.xebia.com/2013/09/01/differences-between-providers-in-angularjs/) for a comprehensive write up on providers